# How do I use NFA's to show a language is Regular with multiple strings?

Tags: regular-language, nfa

I'm having a tough time understanding how NFA's are used in the context of showing how one language A could be equivalent to some other language B. Below is an example that I'm trying to understand.
Why is there a need to hold 5 states in this NFA? 
How does the last step show that xyz is an element of A?
Can somebody explain this example intuitively?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're given string `y`. You randomly select two states `p` and `q`. `p` is where you assume `y` started and `q` is where you assume `y` ended.

Then you try to find a path from your start state `q0` to `p` by following transitions nondeterministically, one transition per character in `y`.

At the same time you try to find a path from `q` to `qf`, again nondeterministically following transitions once per character in `y`.

At the same time you follow `y`'s transitions from `p` to `q`.

If you end up in state `<p,p,q,q,qf>`, it means you've

1. Found a path from the starting state `q0` to `p`. I.e., you've found string `x`.
2. Found a path from `p` to `q`. I.e., you've found string `y`.
3. Found a path from `q` to `qf`. I.e., you've found string `z`.
4. Guaranteed that all of these paths have the same length (`|x| = |y| = |z|`)

Since `x` goes from state `q0` to `p`, `y` goes from state `p` to `q` and `z` goes from state `q` to `qf`, `xyz` goes from state `q0` to `qf`. I.e., `xyz` is in language `A`, which means `y` is in language `L`.